# Change default language on Firefox

Tags: firefox, spell-checking

I've been looking forever for a way to change the default language on Firefox (Ubuntu 12.04). Nothing I did worked, until I just figured it out now. (see my own answer below)

Does anybody know a better way to do it?

Comment: This question, while valuable (I voted up) does not belong on SO but on SuperUser@SE because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your language folder of firefox. For me it is usr/lib/firefox/dictionaries.
2. Note if it is a shortcut, for me it shortcutted to ../../share/hunspell (/usr/share/hunspell)
3. Backup the folder somewhere (copy paste it)
4. Go to that folder and DELETE everything other than the language you want. (for me I kept only en_US*)

This obviously only works if you don't want the other languages. After months of trying to solve this bug, I couldn't come up with any other way. Hopefully Mozilla fixes this bug soon...

Here's the command lines

```
user@user-1015E:/usr/share/hunspell$ sudo rm en_A*
user@user-1015E:/usr/share/hunspell$ sudo rm en_C*
user@user-1015E:/usr/share/hunspell$ sudo rm en_Z*
user@user-1015E:/usr/share/hunspell$ sudo rm en_G*
```

Comment: So, you didn't actually change the default spellcheck language, you simply delete all other languages and left only one?

Comment: yup, it was very frustrating. Hopefully this bug is now gone

Answer (score 12):

I was able to set the default spellchecker by going to `about:config` and setting `spellchecker.dictionary`.

Comment: thank you very much for this -- the mozilla help files and forums were not helpful!

Comment: I have this set to en-GB, but it still corrects in French by default. I do have an English dictionary installed.

Answer (score 0):

It think the underlying problem is that when you use system wide spell check dictionaries only (and no dictionaries as a plugin) Firefox does not remember your default settings (is this a bug?). You need to have at least one [dictionary](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/) installed as a Firefox plugin.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936792/change-firefox-spell-check-default-language/29446115) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184300/how-can-i-change-firefoxs-default-dictionary/576877) question.