# Change firefox spell check default language

Tags: firefox, default, spell-checking

Firefox has come to believe that my default spell check language should be Spanish. My global preferences have English selected:

Preferences->Content->Languages->English [en]

and on a page-by-page basis I'm able to reset the spell checker language via:

Right click->Languages->English (United States)

However, for newly opened pages or new sessions the default spell check language returns to Spanish. I found a workaround here:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/975459#answer-494574

Which suggested that installing a new dictionary would change the default. However, this issue has bugged me for so long that I would like to know if there is a more "correct" way to change the default spell check language.

Answer (score 4):

If you only use system wide spell checking dictionaries (for example, the hunspell package provided by your Linux distribution) Firefox seems not be able to remember the default configuration (is this a bug?). You can fix this issue by having at least one [dictionary](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/) installed as a Firefox plugin.

Comment: note that I found the correct answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184300/how-can-i-change-firefoxs-default-dictionary/576877#576877), but I can not vote or make comments due to my newbie status on StackExchange.

Comment: related bug reports I found: [Bugzilla 776028](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776028) and [Ubuntu bug 1026869](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1026869)

Comment: Thanks, this appears very similar to the workaround cited in the original question. Good to know about the bug report.

Comment: Here is the [ArchWiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox#Firefox_does_not_remember_default_spell_check_language) for this solution **with additional information and references.**

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is no UI for this.  Instead you have to use about:config and set `dictionary.spellchecker`.

Also, Content > Languages has no bearing on spell checking.  This effects what content you're given on multilingual websites.